# Sample code to get Siphon application in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

Does anyone have the link for the sorce code of Siphon application to use SIP(VoIP) in my application.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.
Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0):

http://tharindufit.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/how-to-compile-siphon-for-non-jail-broken-iphone-make-voip-calls-on-wifi/

here has some steps to follow .